# Mongo DB; Postman giving error even though user object successfully updates

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, postman

Using Postman to update a user object in my Mongo DB on Mlab. The user object has an email, username, and password.

Here is the method in question that handles the PUT request:

```
server.put('/edit/:id', (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const changes = req.body;

    const options = {
        new: true,
    };

    User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, changes, options)
        .then(user => {
            if (note) {
                return res.status(200).json(user);
            } else {
                res.status(404).json({ message: 'User not found' });
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res
                .status(500)
                .json({ message: 'There was a problem finding that user', error: err });
        });
});
```

When I make a request with Postman entering in the following JSON object to update my user's password:

```
{
  "password": "skittles"
}
```

The database on Mlab updates successfully, showing the new password.

However, Postman gives me the following error in its console:

```
{
    "message": "There was a problem finding that user",
    "error": {}
}
```

I thought that maybe this was due to the rest of the code continuing to execute after updating the object, so I added a return in the `return res.status(200).json(user);`, thinking that would help, but Postman is still giving me the error message.

Why am I getting this error when the user object successfully updates on the Mongo DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the `ReferenceError` of `note` variable.

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, changes, options)
        .then(user => {
            if (user) {
                return res.status(200).json(user);
            } else {
                res.status(404).json({ message: 'User not found' });
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res
                .status(500)
                .json({ message: 'There was a problem finding that user', error: err });
        });
```

In future, if something comes to `catch` block, print it with the `console.log`. Because, you can't send it with `.json()`.

If you want to know the error in the response, try this,

```
res.json({
   message: 'something',
   error: (err && err.message) || 'Not available',
})
```

Comment: Still stumbling over the simplest things after three years of studying programming. That fixed it, greatly appreciated.

Comment: It happens, chill. Just get experienced :)